# Why my nav button gets out of the layout when I don't set it to absolute?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-animations, css-position

Basically, I want to make a nav button that when you hover it, it becomes a cross.

The thing is that it works almost perfectly fine but only when I apply "Position: absolute" to the container of the three lines. But when I don't do that, it all breaks and the three lines get out of the layout. Why?

Here is the css code:

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.icon {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 50px;
}

.icon div {
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 5em;
    line-height: 10px;
}

.icon:hover div:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.icon:hover div:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-40%, 100%)
}

.icon:hover div:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Nav.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="icon">
            <div class="line">⎯</div>
            <div class="line">⎯</div>
            <div class="line">⎯</div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Navigation</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Next</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Something</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

But without `position: absolute` to `.icon`, see what happens:

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.icon {
    margin: 50px;
}

.icon div {
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 5em;
    line-height: 10px;
}

.icon:hover div:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Nav.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="icon">
            <div class="line">⎯</div>
            <div class="line">⎯</div>
            <div class="line">⎯</div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Navigation</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Next</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Something</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Why? What setting the container out of the usual flow has anything to do with this strange behavior?

Comment: @RolandStarke It helps! But I still don't get why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your `icon` div to `display: inline-block`.

Try putting a border around your div on your code and you'll see it takes all the width - `margin: 50px` because `div`s by default are displayed block. That means that when you rotate it, it rotates as the center was on the center of the page, so the rotation takes up much more space, that's why it looks like they're going on a walk.

I suggest to use backgrounds or borders when testing so you can better see what's going on.

Here the code. I added some classes so it's easier to read.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.icon {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.line {
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 10px;
}

.icon:hover > .line-one {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-40%, 100%);
}

.icon:hover > .line-two {
  opacity: 0;
}

.icon:hover > .line-three {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="icon">
            <div class="line line-one">⎯</div>
            <div class="line line-two">⎯</div>
            <div class="line line-three">⎯</div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Navigation</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Next</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Something</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```